# Create ActionLink with Attached Parameters With ASP.Net MVC Without Declaring Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

I am interested in creating URL with ASP.Net MVC 3 that has a QuerySting Attached but everywhere I look it says I need to Create a Route. Does anyone know how to create this:

```
    <a href="/home/search/1120000000?page=3">Next Page</a>
```

Using the Html.ActionLink helper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next Page",
                 "search",
                 new{controller="home", id="1120000000", page="3"})
```

if you have the default route setup it will produce

```
<a href="/home/search/1120000000?page=3">Next Page</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is much better than the ways I had been seeing and also a lot better than the one just stumbled upon.